# Setting up Mono/ASP.NET 4.0 on Apache2/Ubuntu: Virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, mono

I'm attempting to setup Mono/ASP.NET 4.0 on my Apache server (which is running on Ubuntu). Thus far, I've been following a few tutorials/scripts supplied [here](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/category/dotnet/mono/), and [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono).

As of now:

- Apache 2.2 is installed (accessible via 'localhost')
- Mono 2.10.5 is installed

However, I'm struggling to configure Apache correctly... apparently the Virtual Host setting isn't doing its job and invoking the mod_mono plugin, nor is it even pulling source from the proper directory. While the Virtual Host setting points to '\srv\www\localhost', it clearly is pulling content instead from 'var/www/', which I've found is the default DocumentRoot for virtual hosts.

I can confirm:

- "/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mod-mono-server4" exists.
- Virtual hosts file is being read, since undoing the comment in the main httpd.conf changed the root directory from 'htdocs' to 'var/www/'
- The Mono installation is at least semi-capable of running ASP 4.0, as evidenced by running XSP, navigating to 0.0.0.0:8080/ and getting an ASP.NET style error page with "Mono ASP 4.0.x" at the bottom.

Can anyone point out how to fix these configurations and get Mono linked up with Apache?

Here are my configs and relevant information:

***/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:***

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/foo_log".

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#

ServerAdmin david@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#

ServerName localhost:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or 0 for unlimited
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges
#MaxRanges 0

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

*** /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf ***

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
 ServerAdmin david@localhost
  DocumentRoot "/srv/www/localhost"

    # MonoServerPath can be changed to specify which version of ASP.NET is hosted
    # mod-mono-server1 = ASP.NET 1.1 / mod-mono-server2 = ASP.NET 2.0
    # For SUSE Linux Enterprise Mono Extension, uncomment the line below:
    # MonoServerPath localhost "/opt/novell/mono/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    # For Mono on openSUSE, uncomment the line below instead:
    MonoServerPath localhost "/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mod-mono-server4"

    # To obtain line numbers in stack traces you need to do two things: 
    # 1) Enable Debug code generation in your page by using the Debug="true" 
    #    page directive, or by setting <compilation debug="true" /> in the 
    #    application's Web.config
    # 2) Uncomment the MonoDebug true directive below to enable mod_mono debugging
    MonoDebug localhost true

    # The MONO_IOMAP environment variable can be configured to provide platform abstraction
    # for file access in Linux.  Valid values for MONO_IOMAP are:
    #    case
    #    drive
    #    all
    # Uncomment the line below to alter file access behavior for the configured application
    MonoSetEnv localhost PATH=/opt/mono-2.10/bin:$PATH;LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mono-2.10/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
    #
    # Additional environtment variables can be set for this server instance using 
    # the MonoSetEnv directive.  MonoSetEnv takes a string of 'name=value' pairs 
    # separated by semicolons.  For instance, to enable platform abstraction *and* 
    # use Mono's old regular expression interpreter (which is slower, but has a
    # shorter setup time), uncomment the line below instead:
    # MonoSetEnv localhost MONO_IOMAP=all;MONO_OLD_RX=1

    MonoApplications localhost "/:/srv/www/localhost"
    <Location "/">
       Allow from all
       Order allow,deny
       MonoSetServerAlias localhost
       SetHandler mono
       SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
       SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
     </Location>
     <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
      </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

***mono -V output:***

```
root@david-ubuntu:~# mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-5ubuntu3)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the mono runtime, then what you need to make your applications work is to create a symbolic link to the new installation of mono ... and mono-V when writing instead of leaving the version 2.6.7 using version 2.10, the link you create is as follows:

```
    ln -s -f /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono /usr/bin/mono
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the module loaded appropriately?

- **LoadModule mono_module /path/to/mono/module/mod_mono.so**

Also, you need to add this in your config:

- **AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx**
- **DirectoryIndex Default.aspx**

Applications (virtual hosts) are defined in .webapp files => **hostname.com.webapp**

```
<apps>
        <web-application>
                <name>Name of site</name>
                <vpath>/</vpath>
                <path>/path/to/root/</path>
                <vhost>hostname.com</vhost>
        </web-application>
</apps>
```

And in order to load your .webapp files, add this to your config:

- **MonoApplicationsConfigDir default /path/to/dir/with/webappfiles**

I hope this helps or atleast point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but how about this:

1. Install mod_mono

   sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server4

2.Configure mod_mono

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_mono.conf

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
DirectoryIndex index.aspx

Include /etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf
```

3. Setup your Virtual Host

Prepare your public directory

```
mkdir /home/alduin/www
```

Make your directory readable by Apache

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/alduin/www
```

Create apache configuration file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

ServerName yourdomain.co.uk
ServerAlias www.yourdomain.co.uk
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.co.uk-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.co.uk-access.log combined
DocumentRoot /home/alduin/www/
 MonoServerPath yourdomain.co.uk "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
 MonoDebug yourdomain.co.uk true # disable it in production
 MonoApplications yourdomain.co.uk "/:/home/alduin/"

<Location "/">
 Allow from all
 Order allow,deny
 MonoSetServerAlias yourdomain.co.uk
 SetHandler mono
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary

 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
```

Restart

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For more info check this post: 
http://r2d2.cc/2014/03/25/asp-net-mvc-under-linux-with-mono/